# how do i leave this while loop in my c# exercise?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

im trying to make a fake little password guesser for an exercise in class, but i cant seem to break out of this while loop? im quite new to using break/goto so im not sure how to use those, especially since my teacher has never mentioned them.

the goal is that the password guesser stops after you get the password from 3 times and your access is denied.

this is my code so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //password guesser

    string correctPassword = "kittens";
    bool isPasswordCorrect = false;
    int maxAttempts = 3;
    int attempts = 0;
    
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your password: ");
        string userPassword = Console.ReadLine();

        if (userPassword == correctPassword) 
        {
            isPasswordCorrect = true;
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered the correct password!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect password! Please try again.");
            Console.WriteLine("Hint: the best fluffy animals");
            attempts++;
        }

        if (!isPasswordCorrect)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("beep boop! Too many tries, access denied!");
        }
    } 
    
    while (attempts < maxAttempts || !isPasswordCorrect);
}
```

i tried break but i cant seem to get it to work

Comment: I think your or operator should be an and operator in the while statement. `break` should work aswell.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest turning `do .. while` into `for`; you can *extract a method* for password validation. Having a method, we can use `return` to break the loop:

```
private static bool IsPasswordValid(string correctPassword, 
                                    string hint = default, 
                                    int maxAttempts = 3) {
  for (int attempt = 0; attempt < maxAttempts; ++attempt) {
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your password: ");

    if (Console.ReadLine() == correctPassword) {
      Console.WriteLine("You have entered the correct password!");

      return true;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect password! Please try again.");

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hint))
      Console.WriteLine("Hint: the best fluffy animals");
  }

  Console.WriteLine("beep boop! Too many tries, access denied!");

  return false;
}
```

Then you can use it as follow:

```
if (IsPasswordValid("kittens", "Hint: the best fluffy animals")) {
  // User provided correct password
}
else {
  // User failed to provide correct password
}
```

Comment: This is a good, easy to understand solution. It's good teaching. One thing, the default value of the hint parameter should be the default hint. That would simplify the code and reduce duplication. Otherwise, it's probably best to make the parameter required.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad: I've put no hint as a default one; typically, I expect calls like `if (IsPasswordValid("kittens")) { ... }` or `if (IsPasswordValid("butterflies")) { ... }` etc. Since `hint` depends on `correctPassword` I doubt if I can provider a better default for `hint`.

Comment: Fair enough. It's just an awkward design but I suppose it didn't start with you.

Answer (score 2):

The loop should continue if attempts is < as maxAttempts and no correct password is entered, so you need and in the while , not or:

```
while (attempts < maxAttempts && !isPasswordCorrect);
```